# How to insert script tag to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flipclock

I'm trying to do the countdown clock in React, but problems with the script tag

```
      var Product = this.state.productList.map(function (product, i) {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 grid-figure" key={i+1}>
                <figure>
                    <div className="rewardImage thumbnail_wrapper">
                        <img src={product.picture} alt="#"/>
                    </div>
                    <figcaption className="title">{product.name}</figcaption>
                    <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 padding-none">
                        <figcaption className="price">{product.cost_min}</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 padding-none">
                        <figcaption className="due"><div className="clock-builder-output"></div></figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-none">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={self.clickHandler.bind(self, product.productId)}>ĐẤU GIÁ</button>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){
                    FlipClock.Lang.Custom = {
                        days:'Days',
                        hours:'Hours',
                        minutes:'Minutes',
                        seconds:'Seconds'
                    }
                    var opts = {
                        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                        countdown: true,
                        language: 'Custom'
                    }
                    var countdown = product.deadline - ((new Date().getTime())/1000)
                    countdown = Math.max(1, countdown);
                    $('.clock-builder-output').FlipClock(countdown, opts)
                })
            </script>
        )
     }
```

it's an error like this

```
ERROR in ./public/js/components/GridProducts.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (73:4)

  71 |                  </figure>
  72 |              </div>
> 73 |              <script type="text/javascript">
   |                ^
  74 |                  $(function(){
  75 |                      FlipClock.Lang.Custom = {
  76 |                          days:'Days',
```

I tried it in componentWillMount script, but how it can derive value "product.deadline".

Using React, should I use are also perplexed with this problem

Comment: You would wrap `<div>{...}</div><script>{...}</script>` inside another div, otherwise, a JSX error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do this.  You should use React's lifecycle methods to interact with the DOM.  In this case, the DOM is available in the componentDidMount() lifecycle method and you would be able to do anything with jQuery inside of that.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class